# How to define value of variable from one function to another?

Tags: javascript

Hello i have this function for example:

```
var dt = new Date(); 
var now = dt.valueOf(); 
function date1() { 
  var d1 = Math.ceil(
    (Math.abs(now - dt.setUTCFullYear(2005))) / (1000*3600*24*365)
  ); 
}
```

And i want to get value from d1 var to another function for example:

```
function res() { 
  document.write(d1).value; 
}
```

Comment: 1) make your function _return_ a value; 2) use it.

Comment: return `d1` in `date1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your function return the value:

```
var dt = new Date(); 
var now = dt.valueOf(); 
function date1() { 
  return Math.ceil( // <=== Change, using return rather than setting a variable
    (Math.abs(now - dt.setUTCFullYear(2005))) / (1000*3600*24*365)
  ); 
}
```

Then call the function when you need the value:

```
function res() { 
  document.write(date1()).value; 
  // Change -----^^^^^^^
}
```

---

Side note: As far as I'm aware, `document.write` doesn't have any return value, so the `.value` on the end of your `document.write` line doesn't make any sense, and will probably result in a `TypeError` complaining that you're trying to access a property on `undefined`.

Side note 2: In *general*, `document.write` isn't a great way to put information on web pages, use the DOM instead. Like most rules, there are exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the local variables of function A from function B you have to put the definition of function B somewhere inside of the body of function A.

```
function A() {
  var variable;

  function B() {
    // can access variable here
  }
}
```